# How to display text from a .txt file with proper line breaks when output to terminal

Tags: python, function, text, terminal

I am writing a relatively basic typing test script to be run in the terminal. I have an example text block which is saved as `text_block.txt`:

```
Roads go ever ever on,
Over rock and under tree,
By caves where never sun has shone,
By streams that never find the sea;
Over snow by winter sown,
And through the merry flowers of June,
Over grass and over stone,
And under mountains in the moon.
```

and the following function to read this in:

```
def load_text():
    with open("text_block.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = []
        for line in f:
            lines.append(line.strip())
        lines = ''.join(lines)
        return lines
```

which gives the following when displayed in the terminal:

```
Roads go ever ever on,Over rock and under tree,By caves where never sun has shone,By streams that never find the sea;Over snow by winter sown,And through the merry flowers of June,Over grass and over stone,And under mountains in the moon.
```

How do I get this to have proper line breaks to mimic the formatting of the text file?

Comment: Don't `.strip()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your desired output by inserting line breaks between all the words:

```
a = ["abc", "deg", "II"]
b = "\n".join(a)
>>> b
'abc\ndef\nII'
>>> print(b)
abc
deg
II
```

However you might want to add a line break at the end, in which case just add:

```
b += "\n"
>>> print(b)
abc
deg
II
```

But you can also improve your code. You can use list comprehension to get rid of some extra lines (it does the same as your example).

```
with open() as f:
    return "".join([for line in f])
```

Removing `.strip()` will keep everything from the file (including existing line breaks).

Or shorter:

```
with open() as f:
    return "".join(f.readlines())
```